# Vue i18n - can not dynamically change locale

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I have a small vue app where I want to implement the vue-i18n plug to make my app multilingual. I have installed the vue-i18n plugin from the vue cli. I have two locales and everything works as expected - whenever I manually change the locale from the.env file to the desired language, the language in the app also changes.However, whenever I try to change it with a button on the frontend I fail to do so.

This is what I have in my i18n.js file:

```js
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'

function loadLocaleMessages() {
  const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i);
  const messages = {};
  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i);
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1];
      messages[locale] = locales(key);
    }
  })
  return messages;
}

export default createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})
```

This is in .env file:

```
VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE=en
VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
```

This is code from a tutorial I saw and they access the locale by this.$i18n.locale, however, this does not work for me, this is how I try to implement it:

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <h2>{{ t("hello") }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ t("message") }}</h2>
    <button @click="SetLocale('en')">EN</button>
    <button @click="SetLocale('nl')">NL</button>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script>
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  setup() {
    const { t } = useI18n({
      inheritLocale: true,
      useScope: "local",
    });

    // Something todo ..

    return {
      t
    };
  },
  methods: {
    SetLocale(locale) {
      console.log(locale);
      this.$i18n.locale = locale;
    },
  },
};
</script>
    
<i18n>
{
  "en": {
    "hello": "Hello i18n in English! (from component)",
  },
  "nl": {
    "hello": "Hello i18n in Dutch! (from component)",
  }
}
</i18n>
```

The error that I get when I click the button is:

> [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting
> 'locale')

I have tried some other solutions like i18n.locale and this.$root.$i18n.locale but they dont seem to work either.

In addition when I try to access the

### {{ t("message") }}

from which message comes from a JSON file from locales folder I get those warnings:

> [intlify] Not found 'message' key in 'nl' locale messages.
>
> [intlify] Fall back to translate 'message' key with 'en' locale
>
> [intlify] Not found 'message' key in 'en' locale messages.
>
> [intlify] Fall back to translate 'message' key with 'nl' locale

My question is, where am I doing something wrong and is there a way to get rid of the warnings that I have when I try to access the JSON files from the locales folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem in accessing i18n.locales in vue components and changing its value dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72109052/problem-in-accessing-i18n-locales-in-vue-components-and-changing-its-value-dynam)

Comment: Hello mo3n, theis question is also not answered.

Comment: Looks like the same question  OP don't post the same question twice, instead edit your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72109052/979052) with additional info, to increase the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: If it helps, I'm using vue-i18n in my project without any issues, and here is what I've done in my [`App.vue`](https://github.com/Lissy93/dashy/blob/master/src/App.vue#L107-L141), using languages imported as JSON files via [`languages.js`](https://github.com/Lissy93/dashy/blob/master/src/utils/languages.js). There's also a [`LanguageSwitcher.vue`](https://github.com/Lissy93/dashy/blob/master/src/components/Settings/LanguageSwitcher.vue) component, for the user to manually select an available language.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using composition, so not 100% sure this will work for you, but this did the trick for me:

Changed from

```
i18n.locale = selectedLocale
```

to

```
i18n.global.locale = selectedLocale
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Does this work for you? I have useSettings where I load settings along with locale. I override the global locale as you have showed and it’s not changing the translations. When I did it using useI18n it worked but I can’t use it now since Im setting the locale outside of Vue component context. It like my components are not aware of this assignment.

Comment: Yes, this is working fine for me. I'm using this exact method in multiple applications. It may only work for composition API, I'm not sure. It changes the language for all components in the app when I call this change. Could be something in your setup of i18n thats wrong as well?